# Which UK visa should my dependents apply for?

Tags: visas, uk, family

I'm working at an MNC IT company and I am applying for a Tier 2 ICT UK visa to work in the UK.

However, the planned duration for the stay in the UK is only 6 months (180 days).

I have two dependents (wife and child) who will accompany me during my stay in the UK.

Should I apply for a visitor's visa for both or should I apply for Tier 2 dependent visas?

Answer (score 1):

The [UK Tier 2 (Intra-company Transfer) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa) permits you to bring family members with you, not on a visitor visa but with Tier 2 dependent visa.

> [**7. Family members**](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa/family-members)
>
> Your family members (‘dependants’) can come with you when you come to the UK on this visa. Your family members must have a visa if they’re from outside the [European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland.](https://www.gov.uk/eu-eea)
>
> A ‘dependant’ is any of the following:
>
> - your husband, wife or partner
> - your child under 18
>
> Read the [guidance on dependant applications](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-for-dependants-of-uk-visa-applicants-tiers-1-2-4-5) before you apply.
>
> They’ll also have to [pay the healthcare surcharge](https://www.gov.uk/healthcare-immigration-application/pay). Check h[ow much they’ll have to pay](https://www.immigration-health-surcharge.service.gov.uk/checker/type) before they apply.

The full criteria and requirements are found in the [Points Based System (Dependent) Policy Guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/603815/PBS_dependent_guidance_Jan_2017.pdf) published by the Home Office in January 2017, and including an April 2017 update.

> **Dependants applying from outside the UK**
>   Your family members must [apply online](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa).
>
> They’ll need to have their fingerprints and photograph taken at a [visa application centre](https://www.gov.uk/find-a-visa-application-centre) (to get a biometric residence permit) as part of their application.
>
> They’ll have to collect their [biometric residence permit](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/collect) within 30 days of when they said they’d arrive in the UK.
>
> They may be able to get their visa faster or other services depending on what country they’re in - check with the visa application centre.